# Are there USB settings in CyanogenMod 10? If so, where?

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb, settings

When I shut off USB Debugging in the developer settings I get a USB Mass Storage prompt upon connecting the device to my computer.  However, for the life of me I can't find a place to shut off this prompt (i.e., turn it into a notification rather than have the window pop up) or change to MTP mode (I'm assuming I no longer get Kies mode — I have a Vibrant).  Does this exist?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you go to **Settings** -> **Storage**, then hit the menu button, you'll find an item called **USB computer connection**.

Here you can set USB settings.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't think to hit the menu button.  Do you know if there's any way to leave it on Mass Storage but disable the pop-up window when I connect the phone to my PC?

Comment: @MatthewRead I don't think there's a way to do this in Cy 10.  However, I think app developers are able to accomplish this.  In the doubleTwist media player app, it has an option to automatically go into Mass Storage for me on USB connect.  So I'm sure someone's made an app for this sole purpose.  If not, I think you're out of luck.  Or install doubleTwist, ;).  Sorry.